# How can I extend a table with multicolumns?

Tags: tables, multicol, multirow

I want to extend this table to get one more "Tab" (a 'TAB 2' right next to the first tab with the same content).

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TAB 1} \\ \cline{2-5}
  & 1 & 10 & 100 & 100 \\ \hline
  ROW A & a & a & a & a \\ \hline
  ROW B & b & b & b & b \\ \hline
  ROW C & c & c & c & c \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

How can I do this?
I tried a lot but got errors all the time..

Comment: Add another `c|`  to the tabular preamble and replace `\cline{2-5}` with  `\cline{2-6}`, for instance.

Comment: I don't think, this will add a whole tab. I added an image so that it's clear what I mean. I want right next to the TAB 1 a second 'tab' that looks the same.

Comment: Your `\multirow{2}{*}{}` does nothing, you can drop it.

Comment: You need to add 4 extra columns to the table preamble and amend the rest accordingly.

Comment: and what will the line "\multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TAB 1} \\ \cline{2-5}" look like? That's what I fail all the time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe one of these is what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{9}{c|}}
  \cline{2-9}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TAB 1} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TAB 2} \\
  \cline{2-9}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & 1 & 10 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 100 & 10 & 1 \\ \hline
  ROW A & a & a & a & a & & & & \\ \hline
  ROW B & b & b & b & b & & & & \\ \hline
  ROW C & c & c & c & c & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|*{9}{c|}}
  \cline{2-9}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TAB 1} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{TAB 2} \\
  \cline{2-9}
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \eqmakebox[H]{1} & \eqmakebox[H]{10} & \eqmakebox[H]{100} & \eqmakebox[H]{100} & \eqmakebox[H]{100} & \eqmakebox[H]{100} & \eqmakebox[H]{10} & \eqmakebox[H]{1} \\ \hline
  ROW A & a & a & a & a & & & & \\ \hline
  ROW B & b & b & b & b & & & & \\ \hline
  ROW C & c & c & c & c & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]